# navigating among different tabs, not able to achieve when using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have two applications, they will be inside an iframe in a site

When i click on a button in application 1 it should navigate to tab in browser containing
application 2 and vice versa.
I have something like the code below in both applications and it works fine when i am using full link of my applications. But when they go inside an iframe, I am not able to set window.parent.name and navigation is not happening

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.name = "Application1";

       </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <a id="game" href="website.aspx" target="Application2">Click for application 2</a>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are hosted on different domains or subdomains you will encounter cross domain issues anyway using this method. You probably want to use window.postMessage to ensure compatibility, there is a good example here:

http://html5demos.com/postmessage2

An example would be:

parent.html

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="child.html"></iframe>
<script>
    var win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;
    win.postMessage('Message from parent', 'child.html');
</script>
```

child.html

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    window.onmessage = function(e) {
        if (e.origin !== "parent.html") {
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = e.origin + " said: " + e.data;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: is this doable even if i dont have control in the main page that hosts my  app inside the iframe?

Comment: Only using window.top, window.post Message you need access both sides to allow the message to be sent